# Accessing Ruby hash value via symbol key returning true not value

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make a basic command line tool using command line arguments (starting simple and gradually building up). I am using Ruby and its OptionParser class to do this. I have the following code:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}

OptionParser.new do |option|
  option.banner = "Usage: todo_list.rb <list title> <tasks>"
  
  option.on("-t", "--title", "Title of task list") do |value|
    options[:title] = value
  end 

  option.on("-c", "--content", "Content of task list (tasks)") do |value|
    options[:content] = value
  end 
  
  option.on("-h", "--help", "Show this help message") do ||
    puts option
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV

if options[:title]
  puts "Created task list with title: #{ options[:title] }"
end

if options[:content]
  puts "Added task: #{ options[:content] }"
end
```

For reference I have been running the clt as todo_list.rb -t Test -c content.

In the final 2 if statements I am simply trying to access the value of the key :content/:title in the options hash if they exist (if they have been passed from the command line), however the program only returns true ("Created task list with title true") / ("Added task: true"), instead of the value ("Test" or "content")

Using p ARGV outputs ['Test', 'Content'] so the arguments are being passed correctly, I think. Using p options returns {:title=>true, :content=>true}.

I have no idea why this is happening. If anyone has a clue, any and all advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check this one https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/optparse-how-do-i-get-the-argument-values/236651/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the option parser that your switches require arguments:

```
option.on("-tTITLE", "--title TITLE", "Title of task list") do |value|
  options[:title] = value
end 
option.on("-cCONTENT", "--content CONTENT", "Content of task list (tasks)") do |value|
  options[:content] = value
end
```

Otherwise the options are considered to be simple boolean flags.

The documentation for `optparse` covers this in the `#make_switch` section:

> https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch

but that's not entirely obvious unless you already know what you're looking for. You usually end up figuring out how it works by looking at the examples and experimenting, then you stumbling across the `#make_switch` method.